# Excel addon for VBA editing

Tags: c#, excel, vba

Need to replace patterns matching regular expression inside pre-existing VBA Excel macros preferably using Excel Forms. How can I create such an Excel addon to appear in ribbon after one click installation.

Being new to this, any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: It's been a while since I last worked with VBA. Can't you just open the macro and use find and replace from the development tools? Or do you just not know how to open the developer tools?

Comment: i am making a migration right now , so end user will be not me

Comment: What do you want to do? Do you want your end user to press a button to find/replace text matched by the regular expressions in the excel sheet itself?

Comment: yeah , i know that is ugly

Comment: Do you have to develop it yourself? I've googled and found http://www.codedawn.com/excel-add-ins.php

Comment: yeah develop it myself, it should modify VBA macros for all excel sheets in a directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59800/discussion-between-fortm-and-nate-kerkhofs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the VBA code via VBA with the object VBComponent.

You will have the change some security options too to access programatically to you VBA Project (in French the option is called "Accès approuvé au modèle d'objet du projet VBA")

```
Sub ModifyVBACode()
    Dim sCodeSource As String

    'Get the source code in a string'

    With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("CodeName").CodeModule
        sCodeSource = .Lines(1, .CountOfLines)
    End With

    'modify your code'

    With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("CodeName").CodeModule
        'Delete the old source code'
        .DeleteLines 1, .CountOfLines

        'write the new one'
        .AddFromString sCodeSource
    End With
End Sub
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks @abillon, I went in direction of doing this using C#. And am using Workbook.VBProject object. Could you tell how to access a macro code inside C#

Comment: OK, same API was possible to be written in C#, thanks